# Cannot logon windows after changing password via net user newuser command

Tags: windows, authentication, passwords, command

I was trying to change my windows password via command:

```
net user Adminstrator newpassword
```

However, I accidentally did this

```
net user Administrator "newpassword"
```

There is no special character in the password

Now I am not able to logon my Administrator account via either newpassword or "newpassword"

Please help.
Thank you.
Best regards,

Comment: You have a typo in the first command `Adminstrator`, it should be `Administrator`, but the password change should work without quotes. Make sure you are running `cmd` as admin.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is an issue for Windows password change command, that you cannot put double quotes in the password, and if you did, the command will be executed successfully but nobody knows what the password is.

I resolved this issue via resetting admin password to default following the instruction at:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ResettingAdminPassword_EC2Config.html
I was lucky I am having this issue with AWS EC2 instance, otherwise I won't be able to resolve like that.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when using escape sequence in command prompt

Run the following command in command prompt with administrator privilege

```
echo EnteredPassword >> C:\ActualPassword.txt
```

*EnteredPassword is the password that you entered in the command prompt*

And your actual password will be available in C:\ActualPassword.txt